# From a list of dates, get a list of the last date available in each month

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time

I wondered if anyone has another or even a more direct way of finding the last dates of each month available from a list of successive dates?

I currently do the following (note: nothing special about `WeatherData[]` here, I just used it to generate a list of dates):

```
WeatherData["KMDZ", "MeanTemperature", {{2007, 1, 1}, {2007, 12, 31}, "Day"}][[All, 1]];
Last[#] & /@ SplitBy[%, DateList[#][[2]] &]

{{2007, 1, 31}, {2007, 2, 28}, {2007, 3, 31}, {2007, 4, 30}, {2007, 5, 31}, {2007, 6, 30}, {2007, 7, 31}, {2007, 8, 31}, {2007, 9,30}, {2007, 10, 31}, {2007, 11, 30}, {2007, 12, 31}}
```

This works fine.  I just wondered if I could think about this problem in a different way.

---

It seems the question needs a clarification.  The starting list of dates may not include every date in a given month as such; it also may not include the actual last date of any given month. I need to find the last date in any month available in the list.

Comment: You know, you could have done `Last /@ (* stuff *)` instead of `Last[#] & /@ (* stuff *)`... otherwise, your method looks perfectly straightforward.

Comment: And `GatherBy[wd[[All, 1]], #[[2]] &][[All, -1]]` == 
 `Last /@ SplitBy[wd[[All, 1]], DateList[#][[2]] &]`

Comment: @J.M. -- I like your conciseness.  Thanks!

Comment: @TomD -- I hadn't considered using GatherBY[] like that.  Great solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your data already has dates in the form {Y, M, D} you could do without `DateList`, and as mentioned by J. M. you can use `Last` in place of `Last[#] &`, therefore you could use:

```
Last /@ SplitBy[data, #[[2]] &]
```

Since as the operation above shows you are only looking at the second column, you might use a numeric operation and `Pick`:

```
Pick[data, Differences@data[[All, 2]] ~Append~ 1, 1]
```

This is actually quite fast ([`timeAvg`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4199042/618728)):

```
Last /@ SplitBy[data, #[[2]] &] // timeAvg

Pick[data, Differences@data[[All, 2]] ~Append~ 1, 1] // timeAvg
```

> 0.00031456
>
> 0.000020992

This can be made slightly faster still by using [the](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5253138/618728) [undocumented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7815181/618728) [properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8612178/618728) [of `SparseArray`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8885943/618728).  (Evaluate `SparseArray[{1}]["Properties"]` for a list.)

```
data ~Extract~ 
  SparseArray[Differences@data[[All, 2]] ~Append~ 1]["NonzeroPositions"]
```

EDIT: The `Differences` methods work on the assumption that there is at least one date in each month, therefore transition points will be characterized by a delta of 1.  However if that is not the cause you would need to add something like `Unitize`:

```
Pick[data, Unitize@Differences@data[[All, 2]] ~Append~ 1, 1]
```

---

For the sake of exploring less practical alternatives you could also use:

```
Reap[
  If[#[[2]] < #2[[2]], Sow@#] & @@@ Partition[data, 2, 1]
][[2, 1]]
```

Or:

```
Reap[
  Fold[(If[#[[2]] < #2[[2]], Sow@#]; #2) &, First@data, Rest@data]
][[2, 1]]
```

(Each of these misses the last date which would need to be appended.)

Comment: Interesting, concise, and elegant.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @Jagra thanks; please see my EDIT for an important caveat.

Comment: With the new `DateObject[]`, one can now also do `Max[DateObject /@ #] & /@ SplitBy[datelist, #[[2]] &]`. Use `DateList[]` if you need to convert back to lists.

Answer (score 6):

Just ask for the 0th day and you'll get the last day of the previous month:

```
DateList[{2012, 2, 0}]
```

> {2012, 1, 31, 0, 0, 0.}

or:

```
DateList@{2007, #, 0} & /@ (Range@12 + 1)
```

> {{2007, 1, 31}, {2007, 2, 28}, {2007, 3, 31}, {2007, 4, 30}, {2007, 5,
>      31}, {2007, 6, 30}, {2007, 7, 31}, {2007, 8, 31}, {2007, 9, 
>     30}, {2007, 10, 31}, {2007, 11, 30}, {2007, 12, 31}}

Comment: Somehow I had interpreted the question as asking how to determine, in a list of dates split by month, the latest date for each month. But I guess your interpretation's the one.

Comment: @J.M. -- Actually you got it right.  Perhaps the question had some ambiguity.  I added a clarification at the end of the original question.