# Find zero crossing in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I'm looking for a function that finds the index of the zero-crossing points of a list. Before I go making my own subroutine to do this, I was wondering if anyone knows of any built-in Mathematica function for it.

Example of what I want:

```
list = {-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,3,1,-2,-4,8,9,10};
ZeroCrossing[list] returns: {3,10,12}
```

Thanks,

EDIT:

Per whuber's suggestion, I'm adding my findings to the initial question, instead of just in a solution.

I've checked LabVIEW (the other language I know well), and it considers "Bounces" ({1,0,2}, {-2,0,1}) and duplicates ({1,0,0,2}) to be zero-crossings. It outputs a T/F value for each array index.

Example:

```
ZeroCrossing[{1,0,2}]
(* Returns: {F,T,T} *)
ZeroCrossing[{1,0,0,2,3}]
(* Returns: {F,T,T,T,F} *)
```

Comment: I take it that `{1,0,1}` should return `{}`? I can't imagine there's a built in function, but some combination of `Split` or `SplitBy` with `Length` and maybe something else should do it easily.

Comment: Yeah, I just ran into the same issue of how to deal with exact 0 values... I haven't yet decided how I want it to act. I'm going to go look at a language that has a built-in functin (LabVIEW, because that's what I know) and see how it treats that case.

Comment: This feels like a duplicate; can anyone recall what I may be thinking of?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've been searching for it. May be on SO?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**There are different kinds of zero crossings:**

- ..., -1, 1, ... is a crossing *between* two values
- ..., -1, 0, 1, ... is a crossing *at* a zero
- ..., -1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, ... is a crossing for a *range* of zeros

**and non zero crossings:**

- ..., -1, 0, -1, ... is not a (transverse) crossing at all
- ..., -1, 0, 0, ..., 0, -1, ... is not a crossing either
- 0, 0, ..., 1, ... is not a crossing
- ..., 1, 0, 0, ..., 0 is not a crossing.

Thus, the output ought not to be just a single index for each crossing, but an *interval* of indexes.  *E.g.*, for `{-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,3,1,-2,-4,8,9,10}` the output should be the set of ranges `{2,4}`, `{9,10}`, and `{11,12}`. From those you can select a unique value for the crossing if you must.  (The mid-range of each would be a good choice, giving `{3, 9.5, 11.5}` instead of `{3, 10, 12}`.)

**The procedure to find these intervals is not difficult or inefficient,** but it might seem a little tricky, so the following code breaks it into simple steps and saves each step for inspection.

```
zeroCrossings[l_List] := Module[{t, u, v},
  t = {Sign[l], Range[Length[l]]} // Transpose; (* List of -1, 0, 1 only *)
  u = Select[t, First[#] != 0 &];               (* Ignore zeros *)
  v = SplitBy[u, First];                        (* Group into runs of + and - values *)
  {Most[Max[#[[All, 2]]] & /@ v], Rest[Min[#[[All, 2]]] & /@ v]} // Transpose
]
```

**Example**

```
zeroCrossings[l = {0, -1, 1, -2, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, -1, -3, 0, 0}]
```

> {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {7, 11}, {15, 16}}

This approach has a laudable *symmetry*: when the list is presented in reverse, we obtain exactly the same set of zero crossings (which is *not* the case for the example in the question):

```
Reverse /@ Reverse[Map[Length[l] + 1 - # &, zeroCrossings[Reverse[l]], {2}]]
```

> {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {7, 11}, {15, 16}}

Comment: I recently had to solve exactly this problem for a computational geometry algorithm: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/33449/664. It was necessary to identify transverse crossings of a polygon's boundary with a horizontal line (for a line-sweep algorithm). Although the numbers would be floats, it is nevertheless likely in some applications that (long) sequences of zeros could occur.

Comment: It seems like the solution (a bit involved though) +1.

Comment: `v` can be written as `SplitBy[u, First]`

Comment: @Artes Perhaps it looks involved due to the way I present the algorithm (which is intended to clarify its working and assure correctness rather than for optimizing speed). For a more compact rendering of this algorithm--which I think compares favorably in length to other solutions that have been offered--check out [Mr Wizard's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10653/91).

Answer (score 23):

Zeros can be removed from the original list, provided that we keep track of the positions of the remaining numbers. Then we only need to detect when the sign changes from one remaining number to the next.

```
zeroCrossings[l_] := 
  Module[{z, nz},
    z[v_] := Complement[Range[Length[v]], Flatten@Position[v, 0]];
    nz[[{#, # + 1}]] & /@ z[Differences[Sign@l[[(nz = z[l])]]]]
  ]
```

---

**Example**

Using whuber's list:

```
zeroCrossings[{0, -1, 1, -2, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, -1, -3, 0, 0}]
```

> {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {7, 11}, {15, 16}}

---

**Analysis**

The list:

```
l = {0, -1, 1, -2, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, -1, -3, 0, 0}
```

---

Positions of the non-zero values in the list:

```
Complement[Range[Length[l]], Flatten@Position[l, 0]]
```

> {2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17}

---

The Non-zero numbers themselves:

```
l[[%]]
```

> {-1, 1, -2, -1, 1, 1, 2, -1, -3}

---

Signs of the non-zero numbers:

```
Sign[%]
```

> {-1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1}

---

Differences between the signs of the non-zero numbers. Non-zero differences, of which there are 4, signal zero-crossings.

```
Differences[%]
```

> {2, -2, 0, 2, 0, 0, -2, 0}

---

Starting positions for the zero-crossings :

```
Complement[Range[Length[%]], Flatten@Position[%, 0]]
```

> {1, 2, 4, 7}

---

The positions where the zero crossings begin:

```
{2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17}[[%]]
```

> {2, 3, 7, 15}

Comment: David, I added my take on your method to my answer, after voting for yours of course.  I like it!

Answer (score 21):

#### Optimizations

Here is a refactoring and optimization of whuber's method.  It uses `SparseArray` Properties to quickly find all non-zero positions, and recasts the `Split` operation as a generic one which is faster than `Split` with a custom test function or `SplitBy`.  It then splits the actual list of positions using my `dynamicPartition` function from [Partitioning with varying partition size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7511/partitioning-with-varying-partition-size).

```
zeroCrossings3[a_List] :=
  With[{idx = SparseArray[a]["AdjacencyLists"]},
    {Max /@ Most@#, Min /@ Rest@#}\[Transpose] & @
      dynamicPartition[idx, Length /@ Split @ Sign[a][[idx]] ]
  ]
```

---

Here is an optimized version of David's method, also leveraging `SparseArray` Properties:

```
davidZC2[l_] := SparseArray[#]["AdjacencyLists"] & /. SApos_ :>
  With[{c = SApos[l]}, {c[[#]], c[[# + 1]]}\[Transpose] & @ 
    SApos @ Differences @ Sign @ l[[c]]
  ]
```

#### Timings

Here are comparative timings for my refactored code versus the originals.  I renamed David's function `davidZC` to differentiate it from whuber's function.

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

SeedRandom[7]
a = Accumulate @ RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, 1500000];

zeroCrossings[a]  // timeAvg
zeroCrossings3[a] // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 2.246
>
> 0.0718
> ```

```
davidZC[a]  // timeAvg
davidZC2[a] // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 1.123
>
> 0.03244
> ```

About 1.5 orders of magnitude faster than the original in both cases.  David's method is an improvement upon whuber's, being twice as fast in this test.

Comment: Very clever! `SparseArray[l]["AdjacencyLists"]` returns the same thing as `Complement[Range[Length[l]], Flatten@Position[l, 0]]`  I really need to learn more about `SparseArray`.

Comment: You can eliminate some redundancy with: `davidZC2[l_] := Module[{z, c},
  z[k_] := SparseArray[k]["AdjacencyLists"]; c = z[l];
  {c[[#]], c[[# + 1]]}\[Transpose] &@z[Differences@Sign@l[[c]]]]`

Comment: @David links to other uses are found in [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7445/121).

Comment: @David I included your suggestion in my latest update, but in my own style. :-)

Answer (score 13):

Here's another way:

```
list = {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, -2, -4, 8, 9, 10};
f = Interpolation[list, InterpolationOrder -> 0];
zeroCrossings = Reduce[(Sign[f[i]] Sign[f[i - 1]] < 0 || Sign[f[i]] Sign[f[i - 1]] == 0) && 
    1 < i < Length@list - 1, i, Integers] /. {x_Equal :> Last@x, Or -> List}
(* {3, 4, 10, 12} *)
```

You can see that it gets the positions, but the presence of a zeros in the third position introduces an ambiguity – did it cross zero when it when from -1 to 0 or 0 to 1? This can be easily handled though:

```
First /@ Split[zeroCrossings, #2 - #1 == 1 &]
(* {3, 10, 12} *)
```

Comment: I was playing with Interpolation for a while, with no luck (sigh)

Answer (score 8):

Sadly, the built-in functions for this don't give the answers you're looking for.

```
Position[Normal[ContourDetect[list]], 1]
```

> {{3}, {9}, {12}}

that 9 should be a 10.

```
Position[Normal[CrossingDetect[list]], 1]
```

> {{9}, {12}}

Comment: You can use the option `CornerNeighbors -> None` for `CrossingDetect`.

Answer (score 8):

Possible contenders for beauty and speed contests are covered by previous answers. There remains few in the "there is also" category with modest, if any, claims for speed or beauty. Among them is `ReplaceList` using rules that represent the required patterns:

Define

```
crsngsRL = Function[{list, pattern},
    ReplaceList[list,
    {a__, b : Alternatives @@ PatternSequence @@@ pattern, ___}
       :> {1 + Length[{a}], Length[{a}] + Length[{b}]}]]
```

Using @whuber's test list:

```
lW = {0, -1, 1, -2, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, -1, -3, 0, 0}

crsngsRL[lW,{{_?Negative,(0)..., _?Positive}, {_? Positive, (0) ...,_?Negative}}]
crsngsRL[Sign /@ lW, {{-1, (0) ..., 1}, {1, (0) ..., -1}}]
(* {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {7, 11}, {15, 16}} *)
```

Further examples with alternative definitions of "crossing" :

```
crsngsRL[lW, {{_?NonNegative, _?Negative}, {_?NonPositive, _?  Positive}}] 
(* {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {6, 7}, {10, 11}, {12, 13}, {14, 15}, {15, 16}} *)
crsngsRL[lW, {{_?NonNegative, _?NonPositive},{_?NonPositive, _?NonNegative}}]
(* {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 10}, 
    {10, 11}, {11, 12}, {12, 13}, {13, 14}, {14, 15}, {15, 16}, 
    {17, 18}, {18, 19}} *)
crsngsRL[lW, {{_?Negative, _?Positive}, {_?Positive, _?Negative}}]
(* {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {15, 16}} *)
```

Zero-bounces:

```
crsngsRL[Sign /@ lW, {{-1, (0) ..., -1}, {1, (0) ..., 1}}]
(* {{4, 7}, {11, 13}, {13, 15}, {16, 17}} *)
```

Up-crossings (from a negative to a positive number possibly through a sequence of zeros):

```
crsngsRL[Sign /@ lW, {{-1, (0) ..., 1}}]
(* {{2, 3}, {7, 11}} *)
```

Down-crossings (from a positive to a negative number possibly through a sequence of zeros):

```
crsngsRL[Sign /@ lW, {{1, (0) ..., -1}}]
(* {{3, 4}, {15, 16}} *)
```

**Update:** Crossing other numbers, say `1` (instead of `0`):

```
crsngsRL[lW, {{_?(# < 1 &), (1)..., _?(# > 1 &)}, {_?(# > 1 &), (1)..., _?(# < 1 &)}}]
(* or *) crsngsRL[Sign /@ (lW - 1), {{1, (0) ..., -1}, {-1, (0) ..., 1}}]
(* {{14, 15}, {15, 16}} *)
```

Crossing another list:

Let

```
 lW2 = {0, 2, 1, -2, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, -3, 0, 0};
```

The points where the list `lW` crosses `lW2` from above or from below are:

```
 crsngsRL[Sign /@ (lW - lW2), {{1, (0) ..., -1}, {-1, (0) ..., 1}}]
 (* {{2, 6}, {10, 16}}  *)
```

Comment: +1 for creativity and flexibility--very nicely done.

Answer (score 3):

I know, I'm late to the party. I needed to find how many zero crossings occur in a real valued signal, and none of the above methods seem to quite apply. Here is what my signals look like:

[image]

For this example you can count and see that there are 24 crossings. Here is a simple function to extract that count:

```
zeroCrossings[x_] := Total[Abs[Differences[Sign[x]]]]/2
```

Obviously this is not worrying about the singular case where the signal happens to just barely touch the x axis. You can extract the positions where the crossings occur using:

```
Position[Abs[Differences[Sign[x]]], 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since V 10.1 there is `SequencePosition`:

Using whuber's list:

```
list = {0, -1, 1, -2, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, -1, -3, 0, 0};

SequencePosition[list,
  {_?Positive, 0 ..., _?Negative} | {_?Negative, 0 ..., _?Positive}] // Sort
```

{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {7, 11}, {15, 16}}

Or, somehow nicer in my opinion:

```
With[{c = {_?Positive, 0 ..., _?Negative}}, 
 SequencePosition[list, c | Reverse @ c] // Sort]
```

{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {7, 11}, {15, 16}}

Answer (score 1):

If there are no zeros, a simple function based on DavidC's answer works fine:

```
list = {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, -2, -4, 8, 9, 10};
Flatten[Position[Abs[PadLeft[Differences[Sign[list]], Length[list]]],2]]
```

This returns {10, 12}.  With a slight modification, it returns the correct positions even if there are zeros:

```
list = {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, -2, -4, 8, 9, 10};
Flatten[Position[Abs[PadLeft[Differences[Sign[list + 10^-999]], Length[list]]], 2]]
```

This returns {3, 10, 12}

Of course, if you are working in the range of numbers around 10^-999, use something even smaller.

Answer (score 1):

1. Map the number list to a sign list
2. Pattern match zero crossing sublists
3. Find positions of zero crossing sublists

In:

```
xs = {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, -2, -4, 8, 9, 10};
ys = {0, -1, 1, -2, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, -1, -3, 0, 0};

zeroCrossing[xs_] := Module[{b, xss, yss, pattern, patterns},
  xss = Subsequences@Sign@xs;
  pattern[b_] = {-b, x___, b} /; x == Nothing || AllTrue[{x}, # == 0 &];
  patterns = pattern /@ {1, -1};
  yss = Cases[xss, #] & /@ patterns // Catenate // Union;
  SequencePosition[Sign@xs, #] & /@ yss // Catenate // SortBy[First]]

zeroCrossing@xs
zeroCrossing@ys
```

Out:

```
{{2, 4}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}}
{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {7, 11}, {15, 16}}
```