# How to find the position of non consecutive numbers?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Given a sorted table, how can I find the position of non consecutive numbers 
in the first column of the table?

```
list = {{1, 3, 5}, {3, 3, 5}, {4, 3, 5}, {5, 3, 5}, {7, 3, 5}}//MatrixForm
```

[image]

How to do I find the row position of the **first** non-consecutive number in column one?
How to do I find the row position of the **last** non-consecutive number in column one?

Answer (score 5):

I would rather define:

```
list = {{1, 3, 5}, {3, 3, 5}, {4, 3, 5}, {5, 3, 5}, {7, 3, 5}};
```

If you prefer for some reasons your own definition you can use `list[[1]]` instead of `list`. To extract the first column use `First@Transpose@list` or `list[[All, 1]]`, for the last column use `Last@Transpose@list`, for `k-th` column e.g. `list[[All, k]]`.

Then there are many ways, let's show a few of them:

```
Position[ KroneckerDelta /@ (Differences[ First @ Transpose @ list] - 1), 0] + 1
```

> ```
> {{2}, {5}}
> ```

Instead of mapping `KroneckerDelta` we could use simply `Unitize` (as pointed out by J.M.), since it is `Listable`. 
Moreover we could substitute `Differences` with subtruction of `Rest` and  `Most` to get the proper result:

```
Position[ Unitize[ Subtract @@ Through@{Rest, Most}@First@Transpose@list - 1], 1] + 1
```

another method without `Apply` for extracting non-consecutive numbers of the last column:

```
Position[ Total[ Through @ { Rest, - Most @ # &} @ Last @ Transpose @ list], 0] + 1
```

> ```
>  {{2}, {3}, {4}, {5}}
> ```

A related discussion useful for the problem at hand you can find reading answers to this question [Find zero crossing in a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10640/find-zero-crossing-in-a-list).

Comment: Alternatively: `Position[Unitize[Differences[list][[All, 1]] - 1], 1] + 1`

Comment: OK.  .  .I like the last answer.  .  .So the first non-consecutive will be: result[[1]].  .  .The last non-consecutive: result[[Length[result]]]

Comment: How to upvote to the answer given by 0x4A4D?

Comment: @HpRadojewskiSchäferVon There is one way: Answer your question with his answer and then accept it. Another way: try to convince him to write that answer. Than you'll be able to upvote an accept his answer.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

My original code was padding with 0 was specific for test not general...apologies.

In the test example the position of the non-consecutive numbers in the first clumn are 2 and 5 (correct me if I am misinterpreting).

Applying:

```
fun[u_List] := 
 Position[Differences@PadLeft[u, Length@u + 1,u[[1]]-1], _?(# > 1 &)]
```

to the first column finds positions of element whose preceding element is > 1.

i.e.

```
fun[list[[;;,1]]]
```

yields:

```
{{2}, {5}}
```