# How do I write a condition for Position that uses both the current and previous element?

Tags: list-manipulation

For example, given

```
{57, 3, 40, 94, 9, 84, 81, 93, 76, 5, 7, 76, 38, 9, 23, 95, 49, 0, 30, 3}
```

I'd like to get all the indices at which the elements cross from below 80 to above (or equal to) 80:

```
{4, 6, 16}
```

To do so I need the previous element at each current element of the condition.

All the examples for `Position` seem to use a single `Slot`, or higher `Slots` for nested lists, which makes me think maybe there's not a direct way. Do I have to use something like `Partition` to generate pairs, first? (If so, then I can take it from there; I just wanted to know if `Position` could do it with some syntax I don't know how to use, *e.g.* `BlankSequence` and such.)

Comment: Yes, I believe you need to break it up using `Partition`.  It's not unreasonable to wonder if `Position` works with patterns such as `__` or `___`, but I believe it looks at elements one by one, and matches them against the pattern one by one.  `__` would require a global match.  I think `Positon[arr, pattern]` does an equivalent of `Do[If[MatchQ[arr[[i]], pattern], Sow[i]], {i, Length[arr]}]`.

Comment: By `Slot`, did you mean `Blank`?

Comment: Do take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8740525/695132) though.

Comment: see also: [Finding zero-crossing in a list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10640/125)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just a quick-n-dirty, for huge lists there's faster ways, will update when time permits.

```
f = With[{s = Split[#, #1 < 80 && #2 >= 80 &]}, 
    Pick[Accumulate@(Length /@ s), Length /@ s, 2]] &;

f@{57, 3, 40, 94, 9, 84, 81, 93, 76, 5, 7, 76, 38, 9, 23, 95, 49, 0, 30, 3}

(* {4, 6, 16} *)
```

For large lists, this should be quite snappy:

```
f4 = With[{p = Partition[#, 2, 1]},
    Pick[Range@Length@p + 1, UnitStep@Subtract[p, 80], {0, 1}]] &;
```

Even faster:

```
f5 = Module[{o = Ordering[Join[{80}, #]], c},
    c = First@Pick[Range@Length@o, o, 1];
    Subtract[Intersection[o[[;; c - 1]] + 1, o[[c + 1 ;;]]], 1]] &;
```

And speedier yet:

```
f3 = Module[{p},
    p = Pick[Range@Length@#, UnitStep[Subtract[#, 80]], 1];
    If[p =!= {} && p[[1]] == 1, p = Rest@p];
    p[[Pick[Range@Length@p, 
       UnitStep@Subtract[#[[Subtract[p, 1]]], 80], 0]]]] &;
```

As a comparison, the other answers (so far):

```
sza = ReplaceList[#, {pre___, x_, y_, ___} /; x < 80 <= y :> 
     Length[{pre}] + 2] &;

kug1 = With[{lst = #}, 
    Select[Range[2, Length@lst], lst[[# - 1]] < 80 <= lst[[#]] &]] &;

kug2 = With[{lst = #}, 
    Pick[Range[2, Length@lst], 
     lst[[# - 1]] < 80 <= lst[[#]] & /@ Range[2, Length@lst]]] &;

ubp = (Flatten@Position[Partition[Sign[# - 80], 2, 1], {-1, 1 | 0}] + 
     1) &;
```

N.B.: The first three have been fixed to return results as in OP - as written they were not. The `0` alternative was added to *ubpdqn*`s solution to handle equality.

Using `test = RandomInteger[{0, 160}, 110000];` as a test list that will have many transitions, and incrementally increasing the amount of it used:

[image]

It can be seen the `Replace` based solution quickly becomes unusably slow, *Kguler*'s both perform well (and remarkably similarly), `f` leads those by roughly 50%, `f4` is about 4X faster yet, *ubpdqn*'s `Sign`-based solution falls neatly between `f` and `f4`, `f5` beats those, and `f3` handily beats all (it's buried in the noise of the plot). As usual, all timings on the loungebook.

Comment: +1 But please change the color of the f3 curve

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to do this with `Position` without breaking the list up using `Partition[list, 2, 1]` first.  `Position` looks at elements *one by one*, and tests each for a match against the pattern.  While we can use a pattern such as `__` (`BlankSequence[]`), it won't behave any differently from `_` (`Blank[]`) in `Position` because it will never be tested against the full list, only against individual list elements.

A trick to use a single pattern matching to find positions of correlated elements is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8740525/695132), but it doesn't use `Position`.  Applied to your problem, we get:

```
ReplaceList[list, {pre___, x_, y_, ___} /; x < 80 <= y :> Length[{pre}] + 1]
```

This is probably not the best way to solve the problem, but it is interesting in that it fully relies on pattern matching, just like `Position`.

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = {57, 3, 40, 94, 9, 84, 81, 93, 76, 5, 7, 76, 38, 9, 23, 95, 49,  0, 30, 3}
Select[Range[2, Length@lst], lst[[# - 1]] < 80 < lst[[#]] &]
(* {4, 6, 16} *)

Pick[Range[2, Length@lst], lst[[# - 1]] < 80 < lst[[#]] & /@ Range[2, Length@lst]]
(* {4, 6, 16} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps:

```
test = {57, 3, 40, 94, 9, 84, 81, 93, 76, 5, 7, 76, 38, 9, 23, 95, 49,
    0, 30, 3};
Position[Partition[Sign[test - 80], 2, 1], {-1, 1}] + 1
```

The +1, to get when crossed, would have to modify for equality cases, eg using Alternatives`

Answer (score 3):

Just using a chisel to drive a screw:

```
l = {57, 3, 40, 94, 9, 84, 81, 93, 76, 5, 7, 76, 38, 9, 23, 95, 49, 0,  30, 3};
f = Interpolation[l, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
NDSolve[{k'[x] == f'@x, k[1] == f[1], 
         WhenEvent[k[x] == 80, If[f'[x] >= 0, Print[Ceiling@x]]]},
         k[x], {x, 1, Length@l}]

(* 4,6,16 *)
```

Comment: This made me giggle, +1.

Comment: @rasher That was the (not) hidden intention :)

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {57, 3, 40, 94, 9, 84, 81, 93, 76, 5, 7, 76, 38, 9, 23, 95, 49, 0, 30, 3};
```

Using `SequencePosition` (new in 10.1)

```
Last /@ SequencePosition[list, {a_ /; a < 80, b_ /; b >= 80}]
```

{4, 6, 16}

Answer (score 2):

Using `SequenceCases` and `SubsetPosition`:

```
list = {57, 3, 40, 94, 9, 84, 81, 93, 76, 5, 7, 76, 38, 9, 23, 95, 49, 0, 30, 3};

pairs = Alternatives @@ SequenceCases[list, {x_, y_} /; x < 80 <= y]

(*{40, 94} | {9, 84} | {23, 95}*)

Union@(Last @@@ SubsetPosition[list, pairs])

(*{4, 6, 16}*)
```