# How to find position where a sequence drops off to zero

Tags: list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

Suppose I have a sequence

`seq = {0,0,0,1,2,3,1,0,0,0,4,5,8,0}`

and I want to find the first position after which the sequence drops to zero (which in this case, is position 7).

Obviously if I want to find all the nonzero elements I could use something like

```
SparseArray[seq]["NonzeroPositions"]
```

or even

```
Position[seq,_?(# > 0 & )]
```

But what about the place where the sequence drops to zero for the first time, which apparently involves at least two conditionals?

Comment: Try `Length[First[Split[seq, #1 <= #2 || #2 != 0 &]]]`.

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Nearly a duplicate [(10640)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10640/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SequencePosition[seq,{_?Positive,0}][[1,1]]
```

or

```
Min@SequencePosition[seq, {_?Positive, 0}] (*thanks: corey979 *)
```

> 7

To get the position of the first zero preceeded by a positive number:

```
SequencePosition[seq,{_?Positive,0}][[1,2]]
```

or

```
Max@SequencePosition[seq, {_?Positive, 0}, 1]
```

> 8

For versions before 10.1, you can use `Cases`

```
Cases[seq,{a___,b:Except[0],0,___}:>Length[{a,b}],{0,Infinity}][[1]]
```

> 7

Comment: Mathematica customarily uses one-based indexing, so I think you need to add 1 to get the most useful answer (though not what the OP asked for!)

Comment: @mikado, good point. I revised the answer with an alternative way to get 8 as the output.

Comment: Also: `Min@SequencePosition[seq, {_?Positive, 0}]`

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure I quite understand the question.

"*I want to find the first position where the sequence drops to zero*"

From this description and looking at sequence I would select position 8 rather 7 for that location.

```
seq = {0,0,0,1,2,3,1,0,0,0,4,5,8,0}
```

I infer that you want non-zero digits followed by a zero and want the location of that zero.

Here is something that is not elegant but works

```
First@Select[
  Flatten@Position[seq, 0] ,
  # > First@Flatten@Position[seq, x_ /; x != 0] &
  ]

(* 8 *)
```

To break it down

```
Flatten@Position[seq, 0]
(* {1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 14} *)
```

gives the zero positions and

```
Flatten@Position[seq, x_ /; x != 0]
(* {4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13} *)
```

gives the non-zero positions, the first of these is position 4.

I want to select from the group of zero positions the location which first exceeds the first non-zero digit (4), which is 8 for this example.

```
First@Select[
  Flatten@Position[seq, 0] ,
  # > First@Flatten@Position[seq, x_ /; x != 0] &
  ]
```

Comment: I edited my post after you started writing your answer. It now reads "I want to find the first position after which the sequence drops to zero". In either case the two are almost the same thing with a difference of one.

Answer (score 4):

Very straightforward:

```
i = 1;
While[Not[seq[[i]] > seq[[i + 1]] && seq[[i + 1]] == 0], i++]
i
```

> 7

---

**Timings**

```
n = 10^4;
seq = Insert[RandomInteger[{1, 9}, n], 0, n - RandomInteger[{10, 100}]];

Position[seq, 0]
```

> {{9919}}

[kglr's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128222/22013):

```
SequencePosition[seq, {_?Positive, 0}][[1, 1]] // RepeatedTiming
Min@SequencePosition[seq, {_?Positive, 0}] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.00239, 9918}
>
> {0.00239, 9918}

```
SequencePosition[seq, {_?Positive, 0}][[1, 2]] // RepeatedTiming
Max@SequencePosition[seq, {_?Positive, 0}, 1] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.00239, 9919}
>
> {0.00237, 9919}

```
Cases[seq, {a___, b : Except[0], 0, ___} :> Length[{a, b}], 
    {0, Infinity}][[1]] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.00071, 9918}

`Cases` is the fastest, and an order of magnitude faster than `SequencePosition`.

[Jack LaVigne's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128220/22013):

```
First@Select[
   Flatten@Position[seq, 0], # > 
     First@Flatten@Position[seq, x_ /; x != 0] &] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.0091, 9919}

[march's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128238/22013):

```
FirstPosition[seq /. {y : Longest[0 ..], x__} :> Join[{y} + 1, {x}], 
   0] - 1 // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.281, {9918}}

The slowest method.

```
FirstPosition[Partition[seq, 2, 1], {Except[0], 0}] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.0023, {9918}}

[J.M.'s comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128218/how-to-find-position-where-a-sequence-drops-off-to-zero/128243#comment346841_128218):

```
Length[First[Split[seq, #1 <= #2 || #2 != 0 &]]] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.00608, 9918}

---

[**My answer**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128243/22013):

```
(i = 1; While[Not[seq[[i]] > seq[[i + 1]] && seq[[i + 1]] == 0], i++];
   i) // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.01701, 9914}
>
> 9918

Not competitive in timing, but straightforward in coding.

Comment: Mine is slow because of the pre-processing. It would be competitive if I could figure out a fast way of cutting off the leading 0's...

Comment: I think there may be some problems with your timing. If you only test the `While` expression without resetting `i`, the loop will do nothing and return from after the first time. The timing is significantly different if you include `i=1`. You can also observe the output of `i = 1;TracePrint[While[i < 5, ++i]; // RepeatedTiming, _ < _]`

Comment: @happyfish Thanks, nice observation. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
FirstPosition[seq /. {y : Longest[0 ..], x__} :> Join[{y} + 1, {x}], 0] - 1
```

The pre-processing could probably be done in a nicer way.

In the interest of finding a better way of using `FirstPosition`, I hit upon the following, which still requires pre-processing, but this time it doesn't require pattern-matching in the pre-processing:

```
FirstPosition[Partition[seq, 2, 1], {Except[0], 0}]
```