# Incorrect roots from FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

I am working on finding the permafrost active layer in a specific region and I have plotted depth vs temp. I need to find the root of the depth vs time for every time I have (over 9000 times) and `FindRoot` works for only some of the dates and fails for the others.

I used a While-loop to solve all the roots for the 9000+ times. I put the results into an array, but the array is incorrect due to the `FindRoot` failures.

Can anyone see what is wrong with my code and why it gives errors?

```
Data[[16]];
```

> ```
> {"9/27/08 0:00", 0.87, 0.4, 1.38, 1.59, 1.68, 1.47, 0.82, 0.01, -0.4, -1.04, -1.56}
> ```

```
depth = {0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5}
timei = 16; 
Tempvsdepth = 
  Table[{depth[[j]], data[[timei]][[j + 1]]}, {j, 1, Length[depth]}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0.87}, {0.25, 0.4}, {0.5, 1.38}, {0.75, 1.59}, {1, 1.68}, {1.5, 1.47}, 
>  {2, 0.82}, {2.5, 0.01}, {3, -0.4}, {4, -1.04}, {5, -1.56}}
> ```

```
INTPTempvsdepth = Interpolation[Tempvsdepth] 
Show[
  ListPlot[Tempvsdepth],
  Plot[INTPTempvsdepth[d], {d, 0, 5}], 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Depth (m)", "Temperature °C"}, 
  PlotLabel -> ( "Temp vs Depth" data[[timei]][[1]])]

ALsol = 
 FindRoot[{INTPTempvsdepth[d] == 0}, {d, 1, 0, 5}]; 
ALsol[[1]][[2]]
```

[image: code for 1 time]

[image: While Loop]

From here I manually check the 13th time to see why it gives root at 0.16 instead of ~2.5 meters and it shows this.

[image: Checked specific time]

P.S. I changed the `FindRoot` from `{D, 1,5}` to `{D,1, 0,5}` because the first would give values over 5 meters and values under 0 for the roots due to extrapolation, but the second one gives incorrect roots. So I'm not sure how to fix the code to give me the correct values and give me 5 when there aren't roots.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide code in plain text. There's a reason that copy/paste was invented.

Comment: Just a remark: From the plots, `1` seems to be a bad starting point for Newton's method (derivative is nearly `0` there). Anyway, you can avoid Newton's method and line search altogether with `FindRoot[INTPTempvsdepth[d] == 0, {d, 0, 5}, Method -> "Brent"]`. Might also be a bit faster.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Sorry was preoccupied but put in the code. also @HenrikSchumacher when I attempt the Brent method I got this error `FindRoot: Method -> Brent is only applicable to univariate real functions and requires two real starting values that bracket the root.`

Comment: You can get a good seed for `FindRoot` by [finding the zero-crossings](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10640/find-zero-crossing-in-a-list) of each list. The linking routines will give an index into the data, which in turn you can use to determine the time.

Comment: @IrvinD. Your functions are univariate, aren't they? Then the problem is probably that you used `{d, 1, 0, 5}` instead of `{d, 0, 5}` as your second argument.

Comment: I imagine your function varies slowly over time, in which case another way to get a good starting guess would be to use the root from the last step.

Comment: See many useful suggestions here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91784/how-to-find-numerically-all-roots-of-a-function-in-a-given-range/91785#91785

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find numerically all roots of a function in a given range?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91784/how-to-find-numerically-all-roots-of-a-function-in-a-given-range)