# Plotting Poincare section

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, performance-tuning

I am trying to plot the Poincare section. Is there any other method where I get results faster? I use Table to find points at an integer multiple of \phi, making NDSolve evaluate the solution for every integer m. Can I find the points at all integer m without evaluating NDSolve every time?

```
time = 10000; points = Flatten[Table[
Last[Reap[NDSolve[
   {34*Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t]*Cos[\[Psi][t]] + 
      34*Sin[\[Theta][t]]*Sin[\[Psi][t]]*
       Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t] + 
      4*Sin[2*\[Theta][t]]*Cos[\[Psi][t]]*
       Sin[2*\[Phi][t]] + Sin[\[Theta][t]]*
       Sin[\[Psi][t]]*(8*Cos[2*\[Phi][t]] + 
        17) == 0, 2*Sin[\[Psi][t]]*
      (13*Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t] + 
       3*Sin[2*\[Theta][t]]*Sin[2*\[Phi][t]]) == 
     Sin[\[Theta][t]]*Cos[\[Psi][t]]*
      (26*Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t] + 
       12*Cos[2*\[Phi][t]] + 13), 
    Cos[\[Theta][t]]*(10*Derivative[1][\[Phi]][
          t] + 4*Cos[2*\[Psi][t]]*
         Cos[2*\[Phi][t]] + 5) + 
      10*Derivative[1][\[Psi]][t] == 
     (Cos[2*\[Theta][t]] + 3)*Sin[2*\[Psi][t]]*
      Sin[2*\[Phi][t]], \[Phi][0] == 0, 
    \[Theta][0] == 15/10, \[Psi][0] == 15/10, 
    WhenEvent[Mod[\[Phi][t], m*Pi] == 0, 
     Sow[{ArcSin[Sin[\[Psi][t]]], \[Theta][t]}]]}, 
   {\[Theta][t], \[Phi][t], \[Psi][t]}, {t, 0, time}, 
   MaxStepSize -> 1/50]]], {m, 1000}], 2]; plot = ListPlot[points]
```

Comment: Why the option `MaxStepSize -> 1/50`?

Comment: It is a random choice. I could have taken it to be 1/100.

Comment: Why not `MaxStepSize -> 1`?

Comment: It looks like you are computing the same quantity (i.e., Sin[theta], etc) at each iteration.  Perhaps, use With[{st=Sin[theta],…},equations] to avoid superfluous numerical evaluations?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get your suggestion

Comment: User @ plus username to notify people of a reply (e.g. @CraigCarter). I think what Craig is saying is that nothing really changes in the calls to `NDSolve[]` except the `WhenEvent`. So you could just do one call and find when `Mod[\[Phi][t], m*Pi] == 0` afterwards. Alternatively, you can figure out all the data for `m > 1` just from `m == 1` by sampling every m-th reaped data point.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2.  What I was getting at is that your equations have many instances of computing the same quantity (such as Cos[phi[t]]), while each numerical evaluation is relatively fast, repeated calculations of the same quantity aren’t necessary.  I’m just suggesting that you compute once and then  use the result repeatedly at each iteration. Not an answer, but a suggestion for speeding things up.  You could also Compile which will take care of the repeated calculations automatically.

Comment: Convert all trigonometrics to exponentials by TrigToTrue. Collect the exponentials via Cases and define them as products at each time t in terms of the simple exponentials a1=Exp[psi[t]]  and 1/a1 =Exp[-psi[t] etc ]. The complicated trigonometric coefficients become simple rationals.  Use NDSolve[ Print[t]; .... ]  as the first command in the t-loop to see the performance.

Comment: Doesn't look to me it's catching all the mod points as written.  With Mod[phi[t],Pi]==0, only catches one point but  with Abs[Mod[phi(t),Pi]]<10^-3 it catches 77 which is more reasonable since Phi(t) drops from 0 to -400 in the interval of t.   Suggest plotting solutions for one run and confirm getting all points.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2 and Craig Carter. I understand the logic behind the suggestion you have made, but I am unable to code and get the desired result. I will retry and  code again and see if it works.

Comment: I am unable to get the result. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: @MichaelE2, can you help me with Craig's logic? I have understood the logic behind evaluating the NDSolve once (that is for m==1) and collecting data for every mth point, but I am unable to code and get the proper results. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my way, taking advantage of a [zero-crossing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10653) routine by @davidC/@Mr.Wizard from this site to post-process the solution instead of using `WhenEvent`:

```
time = 10000;
ndsol = First@NDSolve[{
      {34*Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t]*Cos[\[Psi][t]] + 
         34*Sin[\[Theta][t]]*Sin[\[Psi][t]]*
          Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t] + 
         4*Sin[2*\[Theta][t]]*Cos[\[Psi][t]]*Sin[2*\[Phi][t]] + 
         Sin[\[Theta][t]]*Sin[\[Psi][t]]*(8*Cos[2*\[Phi][t]] + 17) == 
        0, 2*Sin[\[Psi][t]]*(13*Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t] + 
           3*Sin[2*\[Theta][t]]*Sin[2*\[Phi][t]]) == 
        Sin[\[Theta][t]]*
         Cos[\[Psi][t]]*(26*Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t] + 
           12*Cos[2*\[Phi][t]] + 13), 
       Cos[\[Theta][t]]*(10*Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t] + 
            4*Cos[2*\[Psi][t]]*Cos[2*\[Phi][t]] + 5) + 
         10*Derivative[1][\[Psi]][t] == (Cos[2*\[Theta][t]] + 3)*
         Sin[2*\[Psi][t]]*Sin[2*\[Phi][t]]}
      , {\[Phi][0] == 0, \[Theta][0] == 15/10, \[Psi][0] == 15/10}
      (*,WhenEvent[Mod[\[Phi][t],m*Pi]==0,Sow[{ArcSin[Sin[\[Psi][t]]],\[Theta][t]}]]*)
      }, {\[Theta], \[Phi], \[Psi]}, {t, 0, time}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.129814, Null}  *)

(*https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10653*)
(* Zero crossings in a list *)
davidZC2[l_] := 
 SparseArray[#]["AdjacencyLists"] & /. 
  SApos_ :> 
   With[{c = SApos[l]}, {c[[#]], c[[# + 1]]}\[Transpose] &@
     SApos@Differences@Sign@l[[c]]]

piBrackets = 
   Sin[\[Phi]["ValuesOnGrid"]] /. ndsol // davidZC2; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.012167, Null}  *)

domain = Flatten[\[Phi]["Domain"] /. ndsol]
range = MinMax[\[Phi]["ValuesOnGrid"] /. ndsol]
(*
{0., 10000.}
{-4345.58, 0.}
*)

tvals = With[{tvals = Flatten[\[Phi]["Grid"] /. ndsol]},
    t /. FindRoot[
        \[Phi][t] == Round[\[Phi][Mean@tvals[[#]]] /. ndsol, Pi] /. 
         ndsol
        , {t, Sequence @@ tvals[[#]]}, Method -> "Brent"] & /@ 
     piBrackets
    ]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {3.47713, Null}  *)

{\[Psi][t], \[Theta][t]} /. ndsol /. t -> tvals // Transpose // 
 ListPlot[#, GridLines -> {{Pi/2}, None}] &
```

[image]

I don't know why one wants to plot `ArcSin[Sin[\[Psi][t]]]` instead of `\[Psi][t]`. It just reflects the right half of the figure above across the grid line. However, if preferred, replace `{\[Psi][t], \[Theta][t]}` by `{ArcSin[Sin[\[Psi][t]]], \[Theta][t]}`.

I don't know why one would want to down-sample the return-times.  There are only 1300+ times in `tvals`, so going up to `m = 1000` only makes sense if `time` is greatly increased. However, if desired, one can down-sample with `Span`:

```
timesEvery[m_Integer?Positive] := tvals[[m ;; ;; m]];
```

The total time of execution is under four seconds.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:  Changed WhenEvent to Sow $t$ when $\sin(\phi(t))=0$ as per Michael's suggestion**

Here's my solution using `WhenEvent[Sin[\[Phi][t]] == 0, Sow[t]]` as  per Michael's suggestion.  Takes about 0.3 seconds at 4.0 GHz.

```
    AbsoluteTiming[
 solF = Reap[
    NDSolveValue[{34*Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t]*Cos[\[Psi][t]] + 
        34*Sin[\[Theta][t]]*Sin[\[Psi][t]]*Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t] + 
        4*Sin[2*\[Theta][t]]*Cos[\[Psi][t]]*Sin[2*\[Phi][t]] + 
        Sin[\[Theta][t]]*Sin[\[Psi][t]]*(8*Cos[2*\[Phi][t]] + 17) == 
       0, 2*Sin[\[Psi][t]]*(13*Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t] + 
          3*Sin[2*\[Theta][t]]*Sin[2*\[Phi][t]]) == 
       Sin[\[Theta][t]]*
        Cos[\[Psi][t]]*(26*Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t] + 
          12*Cos[2*\[Phi][t]] + 13), 
      Cos[\[Theta][t]]*(10*Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t] + 
           4*Cos[2*\[Psi][t]]*Cos[2*\[Phi][t]] + 5) + 
        10*Derivative[1][\[Psi]][t] == (Cos[2*\[Theta][t]] + 3)*
        Sin[2*\[Psi][t]]*Sin[2*\[Phi][t]], \[Phi][0] == 
       0, \[Theta][0] == 15/10, \[Psi][0] == 15/10, 
      WhenEvent[Sin[\[Phi][t]] == 0, Sow[t]]}, {\[Theta][t], \[Phi][
       t], \[Psi][t]}, {t, 0, 10000}]];
 ]
```

Then post-processing the points as requested:

```
    theta[t_] = solF[[1, 1]];
phi[t_] = solF[[1, 2]];
psi[t_] = solF[[1, 3]];
Plot[phi[t], {t, 0, 10000}]
dataPoints = {ArcSin[Sin[psi[#]]], theta[#]} & /@ Flatten[solF[[2]]];
ListPlot[dataPoints, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style["ArcSin[Sin[\[Psi](t)]] vs. \[Theta](t)", 16, Bold, Black]]
```

[image]

Comment: Assuming the OP will see this comment, I suspect the OP saw `Mod[t, Δt]` in the docs for `WhenEvent` and assumed that `Mod[φ[t], Δt]` would work. But `Mod[t, Δt]` is a special case for periodic sampling with special handling by `NDSolve`. So `Mod[φ[t], Pi] == 0` receives the generic treatment of looking for zero-crossings, which there should be none, barring round-off error. One might think that `Mod[φ[t], Pi, Pi/2] == 0` might work, since there is a sign change at every multiple of `Pi`; however, there is also a sign change every multiple of `Pi/2`. This then gives too many times, and...

Comment: ...the root-finding complains since `Mod[]` is discontinuous. My suggestion is to use `Sin[φ[t]] == 0` and omit `MaxStepSize`. Then things are quite fast, as they should be. This should not be a computationally hard problem.

Comment: @Michael E2:  Brilliant.  Takes 0.3 seconds that way!

Comment: @ josh, Feel free to incorporate `Sin[φ[t]] == 0` into your code. Or at least upvote my comment. I feel the difference between `Mod[φ[t], Pi] == 0`, `Mod[φ[t], Pi, -Pi/2] == 0`, and `Sin[φ[t]] == 0` should be a highlight of this Q&A.

Comment: @Michael E2:  Ok, updated code as per your request.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the methods that I have used to increase the speed of the computation.

```
whenevent = Table[With[{m = m}, WhenEvent[Mod[\[Phi][t], m*Pi] == 
         0, Sow[{ArcSin[Sin[\[Psi][t]]], \[Theta][t]}]]], {m,2000}];time = 10000; points = Flatten[
 Table[Last[Reap[NDSolve[
         {4*Cos[\[Psi][t]]*Sin[2*\[Theta][t]]*Sin[2*\[Phi][t]] + 
               (17 + 8*Cos[2*\[Phi][t]])*Sin[\[Theta][t]]*
      Sin[\[Psi][t]] + 
               34*Cos[\[Psi][t]]*Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t] + 
               
     34*Sin[\[Theta][t]]*Sin[\[Psi][t]]*Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t] == 
    0, 
           
   2*Sin[\[Psi][t]]*(3*Sin[2*\[Theta][t]]*Sin[2*\[Phi][t]] + 
                  13*Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t]) == 
    Cos[\[Psi][t]]*Sin[\[Theta][t]]*
               (13 + 12*Cos[2*\[Phi][t]] + 
       26*Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t]), 
           
   Cos[\[Theta][t]]*(5 + 4*Cos[2*\[Phi][t]]*Cos[2*\[Psi][t]] + 
                    10*Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t]) + 
     10*Derivative[1][\[Psi]][
                   t] == (3 + Cos[2*\[Theta][t]])*Sin[2*\[Phi][t]]*
               Sin[2*\[Psi][t]], \[Phi][0] == 0, \[Theta][0] == 
    15/10, 
           \[Psi][0] == 15/10, 
   whenevent}, {\[Theta], \[Phi], \[Psi]}, 
         {t, 0, time}, MaxStepSize -> 1/50]]], {m, 1000}], 1];plot = ListPlot[points]
```

Comment: How long does it take?

Comment: @user1163335:  Can you just solve the DEs without Table, Last or WhenEvent? Just `NDSolve` (preferably `NDSolveValue`) the DEs and then just plot $\theta(t)$, $\psi(t)$, and $\phi(t)$?

Comment: As written, looks to me $m$ is unnecessary:  simply run the code once sowing $t$ WhenEvent[Phi(t) mod pi]<small value and plot the results.  May have to adjust integration parameters though.  Haven't looked at it in detail though.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelE2, your logic of using Sin[\phi] is very brillient it worked super fast.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I get to learn so many new ways of solving this particular problem in mathematica.