# Find list position and mapping list

Tags: list-manipulation

Sorry, my English is not very good.

I have two lists:

```
tt = {197, 173, 23, 151, 69, 90, 12, 192, 158, 32, 6, 147, 99, 
  199, 131, 10, 59, 144, 141, 24, 178, 58, 106, 25, 155, 153} 

ii = {{46, 154}, {93, 158}, {125, 214}, {160, 112}, {184, 200}, {203, 
  137}, {230, 266}, {271, 128}, {317, 153}, {362, 251}, {369, 
  252}, {385, 136}, {424, 195}, {503, 139}, {538, 181}, {582, 
  268}, {602, 227}, {621, 108}, {660, 147}, {695, 245}, {739, 
  132}, {766, 242}, {786, 161}, {822, 239}, {857, 128}, {904, 171}}
```

I can find elements of list `tt` that are > 150:

```
Select[tt, # > 150 &]
```

> {197, 173, 151, 192, 158, 199, 178, 155, 153}

**Q1 : How can I find the positions of these elements in `tt`?**

I want find answer, such as:

location = `{1,2,4,8,9,14,21,25,26}`
or location = `{1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1}`

**How can I mapping to the same location to `ii` list which get data?**

Comment: You want `Position` and `Extract`.

Comment: @Nasser thanks you for offer the good information !!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most directly:

```
Pick[ii, tt, x_ /; x > 150]
```

> ```
> {{46, 154}, {93, 158}, {160, 112}, {271, 128}, {317, 153},
>  {503, 139}, {739, 132}, {857, 128}, {904, 171}}
> ```

Or slightly more efficiently:

```
Pick[ii, Thread[tt > 150]]
```

> ```
> {{46, 154}, {93, 158}, {160, 112}, {271, 128}, {317, 153},
>  {503, 139}, {739, 132}, {857, 128}, {904, 171}}
> ```

Some other things to observe:

```
p1 = Join @@ Position[tt, x_ /; x > 150]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 14, 21, 25, 26}
> ```

```
mask = Boole @ Thread[tt > 150]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}
> ```

```
ii[[p1]]
```

> ```
> {{46, 154}, {93, 158}, {160, 112}, {271, 128}, {317, 153},
>  {503, 139}, {739, 132}, {857, 128}, {904, 171}}
> ```

```
Pick[ii, mask, 1]
```

> ```
> {{46, 154}, {93, 158}, {160, 112}, {271, 128}, {317, 153},
>  {503, 139}, {739, 132}, {857, 128}, {904, 171}}
> ```

Also:

```
ii ~Extract~ Position[tt, x_ /; x > 150]
```

> ```
> {{46, 154}, {93, 158}, {160, 112}, {271, 128}, {317, 153},
>  {503, 139}, {739, 132}, {857, 128}, {904, 171}}
> ```

Comment: Very detailed information, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user5990 I'm glad you found it useful, and thanks for the Accept.  If performance is a prime concern in your application be sure to see the `SparseArray` method in kguler's post and look at the timings [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7815181/618728) which relate to a similar problem.

Answer (score 7):

Do you want something like this?

```
Pick[ii, # >= 150 & /@ tt]
```

=> {{46, 154}, {93, 158}, {160, 112}, {271, 128}, {317, 153}, {503, 
  139}, {739, 132}, {857, 128}, {904, 171}}

or

```
location = Boole[# >= 150] & /@ tt
```

=> {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}

and

```
Pick[ii, location, 1]
```

Comment: We are thinking along the same lines. (+1)

Comment: Thanks for, It the great solution :)

Answer (score 5):

```
 ttpos=MapIndexed[If[# >= 150, First@#2, ## &[]] &, tt]
```

or

```
 ttpos=Select[Range[Length[tt]], tt[[#]] >= 150 &]
 (* {1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 14, 21, 25, 26} *)
```

or

```
 UnitStep[tt - 150]
 (* {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}*)

 Range[Length[tt]] UnitStep[tt - 150] /. (0) -> Sequence[]
```

or

```
 SparseArray[UnitStep[tt - 150]]["AdjacencyLists"]
 (* {1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 14, 21, 25, 26} *)
```

For the corresponding elements in `ii`:

```
 ii[[ttpos]]
 (* {{46, 154}, {93, 158}, {160, 112}, {271, 128}, {317, 153},
   {503,  139}, {739, 132}, {857, 128}, {904, 171}} *)
```

Comment: I wondered who would post the numeric solution. +1 :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, was surprised to see that you did not post your trademark;)

Comment: You mean `"NonzeroPositions"`/`"AdjacencyLists"` e.g. [(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7815181/618728), [(2)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5253138/618728), [(3)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7445/121), [(4)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10653/121), [(5)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9797/121), [(6)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16461/121)?  Do I need to hit even a beginner's question with that bludgeon? :^)

Comment: I see that while I was finding those links you hit it for me. :o)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, (that too), but I meant `##&[]`.

Comment: Hi, @kglr. I am surprised that I didn't know Mr.Wizard's trademark>_< . How is `##&[]` related to this question?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard There seems a problem with `SparseArray[UnitStep[tt - 150]]`, it is equivalent to `tt>=150`, not `tt>150`. I can't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: @matheorem (1) see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3705/121; I don't think I would call it a signature myself but I do use it fairly often I suppose.  (2) `SparseArray[1 - UnitStep[150 - tt]]` or `SparseArray[UnitStep[150 - tt], Automatic, 1]`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you so much, Mr. Wizard! Learned a lot : )

Answer (score 3):

Try like this,

for positions

```
  positions = Map[
                  (
                    If[
                        (# > 150),
                        (Position[tt, #]),
                        ("")
                    ]   
                ) &,
                tt
                ];
    Cases[Flatten[positions], Except[""]]
```

for binary values:

```
  Map[
(
    If[
            (# > 150),
            (1),
            (0)
        ]   
) &,
tt
]
```