# Loop through a list and select elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I am new to *Mathematica* and I have no idea how to make a basic for loop work. I want to loop through the elements of a list: `Range[45, 200]`. I want to select the elements (i) for which the following conditions holds: if i mod 3 and i mod 8 and i mod 12 == 1 and i mod 5 == 0 I want to print the element. How would I achieve this?
I want something like this:

```
for i in range(45, 201):
   if i%3==1 and i%8==1 and i%12==1 and i%5==0:
      print i
```

Of course in *Mathematica* language.
Sorry if this is a dumb question but the *Mathematica* documentation is pretty hard to understand. Thanks.

Comment: _"the mathematica documentation is pretty hard to understand."_ — Which part of the documentation for `For` did you try to use for your problem and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/5

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, user6078! As s0rce correctly points out, you don't need a loop here. Successful Mathematica programming requires you to get out of the loop-oriented mode of thinking. [This earlier post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/8) might be helpful.

Comment: @rm-rf - related, but none of the answers there actually talk about `Select` and `Cases`.

Comment: @rm-rf - I understand the documentation, but implementing what I learned with other built-in functions is what I find hard, in this case I couldn't make the `For`, `Range`, and `If` functions work together. I even managed to put a little program together using pure logic, but the output was wrong.

Comment: Please bear in mind that, in *Mathematica*, `For` is not a basic operation--it is quite slow, being intended mainly for some quite specialized tasks. The more idiomatic suggestions given in the answers will serve you better in general unless you happen to know you need `For` in a particular case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to loop through the elements. Have a look at [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Select.html):

```
Select[Range[45, 200],Mod[#, 3] == Mod[#, 8] == Mod[#, 12] == 1 && Mod[#, 5] == 0 &]

(*

145

*)
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind, @s0rce, but I just added a bit from the answer I was about to post, to make it clear that loops are not needed in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I've read a little bit and it seems `For` loops are not appreciated much in _Mathematica_. From now on I will try to avoid them, it will be a problem since most programming languages rely so heavily on them.

Comment: You might like to review this question about loops and mathematica for more discussion on this topic. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to print the result :

```
  If[
   Mod[#, 3] == Mod[#, 8] == Mod[#, 12] == 1 && Mod[#, 5] == 0, 
   Print[#]
   ] & /@ Range[45, 200];
```

the same code without the /@ which may be mysterious for beginners :

```
Map[
  If[
    Mod[#, 3] == Mod[#, 8] == Mod[#, 12] == 1 && Mod[#, 5] == 0, 
    Print[#]
    ] & ,
   Range[45, 200]
  ];
```

"only print the result" means.. that you can' t affect the result to a 
variable.

If you want to affect a variable see sOrce' s answer and add `variable =` at the beginning of his code

Answer (score 4):

Defining a selector function `sF`:

```
  sF = Mod[#, 3] == Mod[#, 8] == Mod[#, 12] == 1 && Mod[#, 5] == 0 &;
```

you can use any of the following functions to select the elements of `Range[45,200]` that satisfy the criteria coded in `sF`:

```
  Select[#, sF] &@Range[45, 200] (*as in @sOrce's answer *)
  Pick[#, sF /@ #] &[Range[45, 200]]
  Cases[#, x_ /; sF[x]] &@Range[45, 200]
  Cases[#, x_?sF] &@Range[45, 200]  (* thanks: @m_goldberg *)
  # /. (x_ /; ! sF[x] :> (## &[])) & /@ Range[45, 200] (* thanks: Mr.Wizard *)
  If[sF[#], #, ## &[]] & /@ Range[45, 200] (* a variant of @andre's answer *)
  #[[SparseArray[Boole /@ sF /@ #]["NonzeroPositions"][[1]]]] &[Range[45, 200]]
  (* 145 *)
```

(Related Q/A:[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19910/125))

Comment: This is a excellent answer, but here is a minor improvement: `Cases[#, x_?(sF[#] &)] &` can be simplified to `Cases[#, _?sF] &`.

Comment: @m_goldberg, very nice, thank you; updated with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Sow/Reap` and `Scan`:**

```
Scan[If[Mod[#, 3] == 1 && Mod[#, 8] == 1 && Mod[#, 12] == 1 && 
       Mod[#, 5] == 0, Sow[#], Nothing] &, Range[45, 201]] // Reap // 
  Last // First
```

---

{145}

---

**Using `FoldList`:**

In order to get more observability, let's use `FoldList` and apply the criteria one by one:

```
FoldList[
  Cases[#1, #2] &
  , Range[45, 201] , {
   _?(Mod[#, 3] == 1 &)
   , _?(Mod[#, 8] == 1 &)
   , _?(Mod[#, 12] == 1 &)
   , _?(Divisible[#, 5] &)
   }
  ] // Column
```

---

[image]

---

Using this result, the criteria that has the most effect can be promoted to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ChineseRemainder`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChineseRemainder.html):

```
f[x_] := 
 ChineseRemainder[{1, 1, 1, 0}, {3, 8, 12, 5}] + LCM[3, 8, 12, 5] x
f[x] /. Solve[45 <= f[x] <= 200, x, Integers]
```

yields {145}

If you want to `Select`, `Pick`, `Cases`:

```
r = Range[45, 200];
crit = Mod[#, {3, 8, 12, 5}] == {1, 1, 1, 0} & /@ r;
Pick[r, crit]
Select[r, Mod[#, {3, 8, 12, 5}] == {1, 1, 1, 0} &]
Cases[r, _?(Mod[#, {3, 8, 12, 5}] == {1, 1, 1, 0} &)]
```

all yield {145}