# Dropping n consecutive terms from a list periodically

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have the following list

```
lis = Range[100];
```

and I want to remove n consecutive terms periodically from the list. For example suppose I want to drop terms 4 and 5, 9 and 10, 14 and 15 etc. I could do this sequentially as follows:

```
Drop[Drop[lis, {5, -1, 5}], {4, -1, 4}];
```

This gives:

```
{1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 21, 22, 23, 26, 27, 28, 
31, 32, 33, 36, 37, 38, 41, 42, 43, 46, 47, 48, 51, 52, 53, 56, 57, 
58, 61, 62, 63, 66, 67, 68, 71, 72, 73, 76, 77, 78, 81, 82, 83, 86, 
87, 88, 91, 92, 93, 96, 97, 98}
```

This gets really messy if I have to drop `n` consecutive terms where `n` is large. Is there a way to do this with just one `Drop` function or a better more compact and efficient way to achieve this where my list is huge. In my example above, `n` is `2`, but it could be `3`, `4` etc. What I want is a general solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The simplest (and probably fastest) way is to use `Partition` with the appropriate offset:

```
list = Range@100;
Flatten@Partition[list, 3, 5]
(* {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 21, 22, 23, 26, 27, 28, 
    31, 32, 33, 36, 37, 38, 41, 42, 43, 46, 47, 48, 51, 52, 53, 56, 57, 
    58, 61, 62, 63, 66, 67, 68, 71, 72, 73, 76, 77, 78, 81, 82, 83, 86, 
    87, 88, 91, 92, 93, 96, 97, 98} *)
```

The logic is: "Take 3, drop 2, take 3, drop 2,... " till the end of the list (the argument `5` is just `3+2`). You can change these numbers as desired.

Comment: Nice, very nice. +1

Comment: @rm -rf There is a problem, but it is easy to fix. Try list=Range@97 and you see that 96 and 97 are missing. The fix is probably to use `Flatten@Partition[list, 3, 5, {1, 1}, {}]`

Comment: @andre Yes, the extra arguments to `Partition` is what you need. I didn't go there because the OP didn't specify what the behaviour should be (i.e., should you take less than 3 if there aren't enough or just ignore it?)

Comment: @rm-rf, with regards to my data, there's always going to be enough, so your answer is perfect as is. But it's good to see the generalizations being offered here.

Answer (score 11):

I am rather amused that my `f2` is considerably faster than `Partition` (here as `f1`).

Now with an additional method I'll name `f4`.

**Third try**.  I'll name this function `f5`.  It is optimized for short `take` sequences and it is quite fast in its element.  It is in a way based on your original method.

```
f1[list_, take_, skip_] := Flatten @ Partition[list, take, take + skip, 1, {}]

f2[list_, take_, skip_] := 
  list[[ SparseArray[PadRight[#, Length@list, #] & @ 
   UnitStep @ Range[take - 1, -skip, -1]]["AdjacencyLists"] ]]

f4[list_, take_, skip_] := list ~Part~ With[{n = Length@list, m = take + skip},
   Drop[Tuples[{Range[0, n, m], Range[take]}] ~Total~ {2}, Min[0, Mod[n, m] - take]]
  ]

f5[list_, take_, skip_] := 
  list ~Part~ Flatten[Range[Range@take, Length@list, take + skip], {2, 1}]
```

Test:

```
a = RandomInteger[99, 1*^6];

First @ Timing @ Do[#[a, 3, 2], {100}] & /@ {f1, f2, f4, f5}

SameQ @@ (#[a, 3, 2] & /@ {f1, f2, f4, f5})
```

> ```
> {3.962, 0.983, 0.952, 0.702}
>
> True
> ```

---

Timings in version 10.1, including the [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) variation of `f2` that [rcollyer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/52/rcollyer) posted as `f3` which only became practical in *Mathematica* 8.

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[
  Cases[{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}, f_ :> (f[#, 3, 2] &)],
  RandomInteger[99, #] &,
  5
]
```

[image]

The same benchmark with `(f[#, 88, 7] &)`:

[image]

And finally `(f[#, 7, 88] &)`:

[image]

Comment: +1, but I have to ask: what labyrinthian path did you take to come up with `f2`?

Comment: @rcollyer [The usual one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19910/find-list-position-and-mapping-list/19922#comment61179_19922), actually. :^)

Answer (score 6):

This is around six to nine times slower than @rm-rf 's :) But you can use it for more complicated patterns:

```
pickpat[a_List, pattern_List: {1, 1, 1, 0, 0}] := 
    Module[{patarray},
      patarray = Flatten@ConstantArray[pattern, Ceiling[Length@a/Length@pattern]];
      Pick[a, patarray[[1 ;; Length@a]], 1]
           ]
```

so

```
pickpat[Range@100]

 (*{1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 21, 22, 23, 26, 27, 28,
31, 32, 33, 36, 37, 38, 41, 42, 43, 46, 47, 48, 51, 52, 53, 56, 57,
58, 61, 62, 63, 66, 67, 68, 71, 72, 73, 76, 77, 78, 81, 82, 83, 86,
87, 88, 91, 92, 93, 96, 97, 98}*)
```

but, say if you wanted to drop the 2nd, 4th, 5th and 7th elements of a list you could call it like this:

```
pickpat[Range@100, {1,0,1,0,0,1,0}]

(*{1, 3, 6, 8, 10, 13, 15, 17, 20, 22, 24, 27, 29, 31, 34, 36, 38, 41,
43, 45, 48, 50, 52, 55, 57, 59, 62, 64, 66, 69, 71, 73, 76, 78, 80,
83, 85, 87, 90, 92, 94, 97, 99}*)
```

Comment: You could also write this as: `f[a_List, pat:{(0|1)..}] := Pick[a, PadRight[pat, Length@a, pat], 1]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks - `PadRight` doesn't do much to the speed in v8 but the `{(0|1)..}` pattern is GREATLY appreciated. I really need to learn to declare my functions better.

Comment: Since you're interested in the subject, if that argument was a *long* vector and you wanted speed (with a valid argument) you might write it as `pat:{__Integer} /; 0 <= Min[pat] && 1 >= Max[pat]` or something similar, to avoid patten matching every element independently.

Comment: +1, this turned out to be really useful for some complicated situation I had.

Answer (score 6):

While Mr.Wizard's [`f2`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21220/52) is fast, there is still faster:

```
f3[list_, take_, skip_] := 
Pick[list, PadRight[#, Length@list, #]& @ UnitStep @ Range[take - 1, -skip, -1], 1]
```

on my machine:

```
Do[f1[a, 3, 2], {100}] // Timing // First
(* 13.023044 *)

Do[f2[a, 3, 2], {100}] // Timing // First
(* 2.665350 *)

Do[f3[a, 3, 2], {100}] // Timing // First
(* 1.461291 *)
```

Comment: I suspected as much for v8, but in v7 `Pick` is not yet optimized for packed arrays so it's much slower.  This was surely part of the "labyrinthine path" I took. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard those timings are on v9.0.1, and the difference isn't quite as dramatic on v8.0.1. But, `f3` is still faster. That reminds me, we should take up a collection to get you a newer version.

Comment: In v9, if you pre-calculate the parts list is a pure `list[[spec]]` faster than `Pick` with a pre-calculated 0/1 vector?

Comment: Would you please check the speed of the `f4` function I added on v9?

Comment: Still working on the first request ... but, `f4` takes about twice as long as `f3` on my machine in v9.0.1.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry for all the demands. :-o

Comment: It looks like my methodology has something wrong with it. I'm getting orders of magnitude difference between part and pick, part showing up as much faster. It may be that my precalculated vectors are random.

Comment: If you're not sick of testing yet I'd like to know how `f5` performs on your system.

Comment: `f5` is slightly slower (0.03 s, on avg, using `Do[..., {100}]`) than my `f3`.

Answer (score 6):

At the time of writing there are 8 sensible answers to this question.  I find this rather imbalanced and would like to add a silly answer:

```
Clear[picker];
picker[d_List] := DynamicModule[{picked = Table[Unique[], {Length[d]}]},
  Column[{Framed[Row[{
      #[[1]], Spacer[2], Checkbox[Dynamic@Evaluate@#[[2]]]
      }], FrameStyle -> Gray] & /@ Thread[{d, picked}],
   Spacer[10], Dynamic@Pick[d, picked]}]];
```

In action:

```
picker[Range[50]]
```

[image: picker]

This is potentially faster than anything by Hypnowizard, depending on the user's competence.

The full inefficacy of this answer can only be appreciated by trying to copy and paste the result.

Comment: +1, because sometimes absurd answers require a great deal of work.

Comment: +1, I didn't see this before. I was laughing for 1 minute straight. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A possibility :

```
lis = Range[100];
ReplacePart[lis, {i_} /; 4 <= Mod[i - 1, 5] + 1 <= 5 ->  Sequence[]]

(*
{1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 21, 22, 23, 26, 27, 28, \
31, 32, 33, 36, 37, 38, 41, 42, 43, 46, 47, 48, 51, 52, 53, 56, 57, \
58, 61, 62, 63, 66, 67, 68, 71, 72, 73, 76, 77, 78, 81, 82, 83, 86, \
87, 88, 91, 92, 93, 96, 97, 98}  *)
```

It can be interesting if the conditions on the index i are complicated.

Answer (score 3):

```
lst0 = Range[20];
dltF = Delete[#1, List /@ Flatten@Range[#2, Length@#1, #3]] &;
lst1 = dltF[lst0, {4, 5}, 5]
(* {1,2,3,6,7,8,11,12,13,16,17,18} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
LinearRecurrence[{1, 0, 1, -1}, {1, 2, 3, 6}, 60]

Table[(-12 + 15 n - 4 Sqrt[3] Sin[1/3 (Pi - 2 n Pi)])/9, {n, 1, 60}]

RecurrenceTable[{a[n] + a[n + 1] + a[n + 2] == 5 n + 1, 
 a[1] == 1, a[2] == 2}, a, {n, 60}]


(*{1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 21, 22, 23, 26, 27, 28, \
31, 32, 33, 36, 37, 38, 41, 42, 43, 46, 47, 48, 51, 52, 53, 56, 57, \
58, 61, 62, 63, 66, 67, 68, 71, 72, 73, 76, 77, 78, 81, 82, 83, 86, \
87, 88, 91, 92, 93, 96, 97, 98}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternately take and drop elements, with an offset, somewhat like `Dashing`.  It is basically an elaboration of rm-rf's answer.  We pad the list on the left for the offset.  `Partitition` truncates a leftover segment at the end of the list, so we pad the list on the right and drop any excess. (See note at end.)

```
skim[l_List, take_Integer, drop_Integer, offset_Integer: 0] := 
 Module[{period, reducedOffset, len},
  period = take + drop;
  reducedOffset = Mod[offset, period];
  len = Length[l];
  Take[
   Flatten[Partition[
     PadRight[PadLeft[l, len + reducedOffset], len + reducedOffset + take], take, period], 1],
   {1 + Min[take, reducedOffset, len], 
    Min[Mod[len + reducedOffset, period] - take - 1, -1]}
   ]
  ]

Table[skim[Range@27, 4, 6, off], {off, 0, 9}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23, 24},
>  {1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23},
>  {1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 12, 19, 20, 21, 22},
>  {1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 18, 19, 20, 21},
>  {7, 8, 9, 10, 17, 18, 19, 20, 27},
>  {6, 7, 8, 9, 16, 17, 18, 19, 26, 27},
>  {5, 6, 7, 8, 15, 16, 17, 18, 25, 26, 27},
>  {4, 5, 6, 7, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27},
>  {3, 4, 5, 6, 13, 14, 15, 16, 23, 24, 25, 26},
>  {2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 22, 23, 24, 25}}
> ```

How not to read Shakespeare:

```
skim[
 Take[StringSplit[ExampleData[{"Text", "Hamlet"}]], {13363, 13385}],
 3, 1]
```

> ```
> {"To", "be,", "or", "to", "be,--that", "is", "question:--", 
> "Whether", "'tis", "in", "the", "mind", "suffer", "The", "slings", 
> "arrows", "of", "outrageous"}
> ```

*Note*: `Partition` will do padding, but it slows down a lot, about 6 times as slow.  The time is similar to *some of the* the answer(s) using `Pick`.  With `Pick` a lot of time is used to construct the pick list, but I don't see why `Partition` would be doing that.  `skim` above takes about 50% longer than just using `Partition` as in rm-rf's answer.

Comment: +1 for the literature application. But I am afraid @rcoyller took `Pick` to the next level.

Comment: I hadn't realized how much the padding spec slowed down `Partition`!

Comment: @gpap Yes, he did, didn't he.  I'll change my answer.