# How to delete some element after a certain distance

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to drop 2 continuous elements every 3 elements,such as I have a list:

```
list = {3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 1, 0, 5, 0, 4};
```

I want to get

```
{3, 5, 5, 5, 1, 0, 4}
```

Any **consice** method can do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[R.M's method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21186/121) with suitable modification:

```
Flatten @ Partition[list, 3, 5, 1, {}]
```

> ```
> {3, 5, 5, 5, 1, 0, 4}
> ```

Or for recent versions of *Mathematica* using [`UpTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpTo.html)

```
Flatten @ Partition[list, UpTo[3], 5]
```

Comment: I used *Mathematica* for almost three years, but it is hard for me to think `Partition` can easily do this..

Comment: I just observed that using `UpTo[3]` instead of `3` slows down the solution with a factor 8 / 10.  Therefore, for very long lists @rcollyer's solution `Pick[list,PadRight[#,Length@list,#]&@UnitStep@Range[2,-2,-1],1]` or this variant `Pick[list, Clip[Mod[Range[Length[list]], 5], {2,3}], 2]` could be considered as well.

Comment: @Fred Interesting observation; thank you. Using variable length output in `Partition` slows it down to begin with, i.e. `{}` is slower than doing a `PadRight` on the original list then trimming after.  I cannot remember where this was discussed but a search would probably find it.

Answer (score 4):

```
Flatten[Take[#, UpTo[3]] & /@ Partition[list, 5, 5, 1, {}]]
```

> {3, 5, 5, 5, 1, 0, 4}

Comment: A small variant, for me easier to understand: `Flatten[Take[#,UpTo[3]]&/@Partition[list,UpTo[5]]]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
Flatten[Map[list[[# ;; ;; 5]] &, {1, 2, 3}], {2, 1}]
```

> {3, 5, 5, 5, 1, 0, 4}