# A question on the function Drop

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, core-language

I use the function `Drop` quite often. When looking at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21186/20253) question, my attention was caught by a use of `Drop` in a way I did not see before. So I read the documentation and found the following description:

Drop[*list*,{*m*,*n*,*s*}] gives *list* with elements *m* through *n* in steps of *s* dropped.

As I read it, this formulation suggests that the list is partioned in sublists of length *s* and that in each of these sublists the elements *m* through *n* are dropped.

```
Drop[Range[10], {2,3,5}]
=> {1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

I expected that the elements 2, 3, 7 and 8 would be dropped. It is only element 2 that is dropped. I get the same result when I replace the number 3 (*n*) with any number between 2 and 10. So with these values, *m* through *n* seems to result in only *m* for the original list.

In the next command I indeed see some periodictity with respect to *s*:

```
Drop[Range[10], {3,-1, 5}]
=> {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10}
```

But I fail to see why elements 3 to -1 in steps of 5 results in 3 and 8. I get the same result when I replace -1 with -2 or -3.

Finally:

```
Drop[Range[10], {5,-1, 5}]
=> {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10}
```

Here elements 5 and 10 are dropped. But:

```
Drop[Range[10], {5,-2, 5}]
=> {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10}
```

Now only element 5 is dropped.

Can someone give me a better understanding how I can predict the result of `Drop`, when used with a list `{m, n, s}`?

Comment: Another way to write it: For `m < n` (and `s > 0` by necessity), `Drop[list, {m, n, s}]` drops `m + s*i` for all `s` such that `m + s*i <= n`. If `n > m` we must have that `s < 0` and it will drop `m + s*i` for all `s` such that `m + s*i >= n`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works analogously to `Span`:

```
list = Range[10];
spec = 3 ;; -1 ;; 5;

MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, list, spec]
list[[spec]]
Drop[list, spec]
Drop[list, List @@ spec] (*your case*)
```

[image]

Comment: @C. E. Thanks, that makes it clear. In the documentation, 'elements *m* through *n* in steps of *s*', the steps refer only to *m*, not to *n*. Now and then it is a disadvantage being a mathematician.

Comment: there are negative m,n examples in the docs if you drill down to scope.