# How to extract first 9 rows from every block of 22 rows?

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I'm working with a list of lists (a large table).

How would I extract the first 9 rows from every 22 rows of this list?

Essentially, I'd like to drop rows 10 to 22, and then 32 to 44, and so on, repeated until the end of the data.

For example, I'd like to turn this:

```
data = {{1,1,1},{2,2,2},{3,3,3},{4,4,4},{5,5,5},{6,6,6},{7,7,7},{8,8,8},
{9,9,9},{10,10,10},{11,11,11},{12,12,12},{13,13,13},{14,14,14},{15,15,15},
{16,16,16},{17,17,17},{18,18,18},{19,19,19},{20,20,20},{21,21,21}, 
{22,22,22},{23,23,23}}
```

Into:

```
{{1,1,1},{2,2,2},{3,3,3},{4,4,4},{5,5,5},{6,6,6},{7,7,7},{8,8,8},
{9,9,9},{23,23,23} (*and so on*)}
```

I am a beginner at Mathametica--please forgive me if this is a repeat question.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `Partition` with a suitable offset:

```
Partition[Range[100], 9, 22]
```

> `{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,    31},
>   {45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53}, {67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72,    73,
>   74, 75}, {89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97}}`

As some have pointed out, this solution needs to be slightly modified if "overhang" is desirable. WReach notes that one can use

```
Partition[data, UpTo[9], 22]
```

for this case in Mathematica 10.3 and later.

Comment: The complete answer should be `Flatten[Partition[data, 9, 22, {1, 1}, {}], 1]`

Comment: To see where are the problems without the `...{1,},{}]` try `Partition[Range[115], 9, 22,{1,1},{}]`and compare to `Partition[Range[125], 9, 22]`

Comment: +1.  From _Mathematica_ 10.3 onwards we can write `Partition[data, UpTo[9], 22]` if we want to keep any "dangling" elements at the end of the list.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks very much C.E., andre, swish, and WReach.

Comment: @swish It wasn't clear from the question that there could be overhang, but good point in any case.

Answer (score 9):

you can do :

```
ReplacePart[data,{i_ /; Mod[i-1,22]>8}-> Nothing]
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 6, 6}, {7,
>   7, 7}, {8, 8, 8}, {9, 9, 9}, {23, 23, 23}}

**Edit**

Here is a more understable syntax, specially for beginners:

```
Table[If[Mod[i-1,22]>8,Nothing,data[[i]]],{i,1,Length[data]}]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
n = 100;
o = 22;

data = Table[{i, i, i}, {i, 100}];

pos = NestList[# + o &, {1, 9}, Floor[n/o]]
```

> {{1, 9}, {23, 31}, {45, 53}, {67, 75}, {89, 97}}

```
data[[#1 ;; #2]] & @@@ pos // Short (* thanks Mr. Wizard *)
```

[image]

Comment: OP wanted to extract the rows from `data`. You have computed the correct indices for the rows but still need to apply it.

Comment: Thanks - I think now it is correct

Comment: For what it's worth `data[[# ;; #2]] & @@@ pos` is a little bit more concise, but you might as well use `Take[data, #] & /@ pos`.

Comment: Updated - overcomplications are a problem everywhere

Comment: @eldo You got my vote :)

Answer (score 5):

```
#[[Flatten[Range[Range[9], Length@#, 22], {2,1}]]]& @ data
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 6, 6},
>      {7, 7, 7}, {8, 8, 8}, {9, 9, 9}, {23, 23, 23}}

Comment: It is an order of magnitude faster to use `Transpose` rather than `Sort`, i.e. `Catenate[Range[Range[9], n, 22]\[Transpose]]`.  By the way this is essentially `f5` from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21220/121.  I need to compare `Transpose` and `Flatten` however.  *Edit* I guess I used `Flatten` to handle ragged lists.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard,  `Catenate[Range[Range[9], n, 22]\[Transpose]]` gives an error message (_The first two levels of {{1,23},{2,24},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9}} cannot be transposed_). I updated with an alternative way to avoid `Sort`ing.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that pretty quickly.  Now your answer is exactly `f5`, excluding syntax.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, right re `f5`. Makes me feel proud:)

Comment: That's very generous, as you surely know I have learned a lot from you.