# How to use all the kernels efficiently

Tags: parallelization, kernel, webmathematica, kernel-startup

We build a project with *Java* and *Mathematica* technologies. For this project we have written a bunch of functions in *Mathematica* and integrated some functions in one `JSP` file. In this way, we made four `JSP` files containing *Mathematica* code. These `JSP` (in which files *Mathematica* functions are integrated) files are linked and triggered by *Java* `servlet's`.

Note: for every request, *Mathematica* (four `JSP`) files should be run. We are using *Mathematica* for back-end computations purpose.

I have two *Mathematica* kernels, thus my **question** is:

How can I use these two kernels efficiently for processing requests?

I've never worked on more kernels than two, if anyone has some experience on that point please let me know.

Comment: After all that time and your 77 questions you still can't format your questions in a proper way. Please make an effort.

Comment: @Öskå It is actually 103 questions but the rest were deleted.  This user is now on an extended suspension.

Comment: @Öskå perhaps it's better when he doesn't format at all: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19912/193

Comment: Though the question in itself is not useless. MSPConfiguration.xml can be overwhelming at first sight. See my answer.

Comment: He was cute, I somehow liked him.

Comment: @Rolf There is no doubt that some of subbu's questions were quite interesting.  We did our best to encourage him to follow site guidelines and think through his questions before asking but it did not improve.  While I am not overly optimistic it is nevertheless my sincere desire that after this third and longest suspension subbu will finally learn what makes a good question and ask only those, properly formatted.  I think we would all be glad to have him back were that the case.

Answer (score 3):

Put a 2 in MSPConfiguration.xml like explained [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.webmathematica.help/html/tutorial/AdvancedTopicsKernelPools.html)

```
<KernelNumber>
2
</KernelNumber>
```

and then your kernels are used efficiently in that sense that if one kernel is busy serving one request, then another one is available if another request happens at the same time the first kernel is still running.