# Working directly on DateObjects

Tags: date-and-time

This relates to an earlier question I asked some years ago, [From a list of dates, get a list of the last date available in each month](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7437/from-a-list-of-dates-get-a-list-of-the-last-date-available-in-each-month).

In this case, I have a list of business dates (no weekends or holidays) as `DateObject`s in the list `dates`.  I want to extract the 1st available `DateObject` for each month in the list.

The following code works fine.

```
Min[DateObject /@ #] & /@ SplitBy[dates, DateList[#][[2]] &];
```

which leads to my question...

Does a way exist to do the above directly on each `DateObject` rather than converting each to a `DateList` as in `DateList[#][[2]]`?

Comment: If you already have a `DateObject` you can get the month using `DateValue[d, "Month"]`

Comment: `GroupBy[dates, #["Month"] &, Min]`?

Comment: @JasonB. - I don't need the month.  I need the the first `DateObject` for each month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way that you are currently working is better than the proposed alternatives.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];

dates = RandomDate[{DateObject[{2022, 1}, "Month"], 
    DateObject[{2022, 12}, "Month"]}, 100];
```

Current method (note that dates must be sorted)

```
t1 = RepeatedTiming[
   min1 = Min[DateObject /@ #] & /@ 
      SplitBy[Sort@dates, DateList[#][[2]] &];][[1]]

(* 0.00127546 *)
```

Using [`DateValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateValue.html) (dates must be sorted)

```
t2 = RepeatedTiming[
   min2 = Min[DateObject /@ #] & /@ 
      SplitBy[Sort@dates, DateValue[#, "Month"] &];][[1]]

(* 0.00940084 *)
```

Using [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) (dates do not need to be sorted)

```
t3 = RepeatedTiming[min3 = GroupBy[dates, #["Month"] &, Min];][[1]]

0.0054788
```

Using [`GatherBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) (dates do not need to be sorted)

```
t4 = RepeatedTiming[min4 = Min /@ GatherBy[dates, #["Month"] &];][[1]]

0.00546494
```

All methods give equivalent results

```
min1 === min2 === Sort@Normal[min3][[All, -1]] === Sort@min4

(* True *)
```

Your current method is most efficient of the given methods

```
{t1, t2, t3, t4}/t1 *)

(* {1., 7.37056, 4.29556, 4.28468}
```

Comment: using `DateList[#][[2]]&` instead of `#["Month"]&` in the second argument gives better performance for `GroupBy` and `GatherBy`. (+1)

Comment: you can also use `Min` instead of `Min[DateObject /@ #] &` in methods 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/281954/working-directly-on-dateobjects#comment702504_281954) the code

```
GroupBy[dates, #["Month"] &, Min]
```

is equivalent to your code and avoids the use of `DateList` to deconstruct the date objects.  The above code is much more readable, and as we see in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/281956/9490) the timing difference is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

```
strings = {"Thu 30 Mar 2023 08:52:48", 
  "Tue 14 Feb 2023 18:02:16", "Sun 5 Feb 2023 14:44:49", 
  "Sat 7 Jan 2023 14:29:20", "Mon 9 Jan 2023 21:16:06", 
  "Fri 13 Jan 2023 01:11:07", "Sun 4 Sep 2022 10:33:07", 
  "Thu 8 Sep 2022 20:03:03", "Sat 23 Jul 2022 22:24:56", 
  "Fri 29 Jul 2022 01:04:59", "Fri 5 Aug 2022 17:29:07", 
  "Sat 24 Sep 2022 08:18:38"};  

dates = DateObject /@ strings  

(*  
  #1[[2,-1]] & is the function that selects the the last date in month.
  #1[[2,1]] would delect the desired first date in mpnth
*)


AssociationMap[#1[[1]] -> Association[Table[m[[1,2]] -> m[[2]], 
      {m, #1[[2]]}]] & , 
  GroupBy[Normal[AssociationMap[#1[[1]] -> #1[[2,-1]] & , 
     GroupBy[Sort[dates], #1[[1,1 ;; 2]] & ]]], #1[[1,1]] & ]]

Association[2022 -> Association[
    7 -> DateObject[{2022, 7, 29, 1, 4, 59.}, "Instant", 
      "Gregorian", -5.], 8 -> DateObject[{2022, 8, 5, 17, 29, 
       7.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.], 
    9 -> DateObject[{2022, 9, 24, 8, 18, 38.}, "Instant", 
      "Gregorian", -5.]], 
  2023 -> Association[1 -> DateObject[{2023, 1, 13, 1, 11, 7.}, 
      "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.], 
    2 -> DateObject[{2023, 2, 14, 18, 2, 16.}, "Instant", 
      "Gregorian", -5.], 3 -> DateObject[{2023, 3, 30, 8, 52, 
       48.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.]]]
```

Of course, I may have missed something. An *Association* is much like a hash map.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

```
dates = RandomDate[DateObject /@ {{2020, 1, 1}, {2022, 1, 1}}, 100];

(* Baseline *)
r0 = Min[DateObject /@ #] & /@ 
    SplitBy[dates, DateList[#][[2]] &]; // RepeatedTiming

(* Out: 0.00248583 *)
```

###### Iteration 1

We have a dedicated function to get the minimum from a list of dates called [`MinDate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinDate.html) (it's slower but it's a built-in :)

```
r1 = MinDate /@ SplitBy[dates, DateList[#][[2]] &]; // RepeatedTiming

(* Out: 0.00680119 - 0.36 baseline *)
```

###### Iteration 2

We can replace `MinDate` with `Min`:

```
r2 = Min /@ SplitBy[dates, DateList[#][[2]] &]; // RepeatedTiming

(* Out: 0.00216887 - 1.14 baseline *)
```

###### Iteration 3

For some reason `First@*Sort` is faster than `Min`:

```
r3 = First @* Sort /@ 
    SplitBy[dates, DateList[#][[2]] &]; // RepeatedTiming

(* Out: 0.00186683 - 1.33 baseline *)
```

###### Iteration 4

Since you'll probably use the gregorian calendar, I think it's safe to get the month out of `DateObject` directly:

```
r4 = First @* Sort /@ SplitBy[dates, #[[1, 2]] &]; // RepeatedTiming

(* Out: 0.000433229 - 5.7 baseline *)
```

###### Iteration 5

We can squeeze more performance by extracting in batches:

```
r5 = (Sort /@ SplitBy[dates, #[[1, 2]] &])[[All, 1]]; // RepeatedTiming

(* Out: 0.000405205 - 6.1 baseline *)
```

###### Iteration 6

We can go all out to squeeze as much as we can using an undocumented function:

```
Block[{temp = Split @ dates[[All, 1, 2]]},
   r6 = (Sort /@ Internal`CopyListStructure[temp, dates])[[All, 1]];
]; // RepeatedTiming

(* Out: 0.0000837435 - 29.6 baseline *)
```

And of course, the outputs are the same:

```
r0 === r1 (* True *)
r0 === r2 (* True *)
r0 === r3 (* True *)
r0 === r4 (* True *)
r0 === r5 (* True *)
r0 === r6 (* True *)
```